# Python library to deal with streamed PCM audio and basic DSP (like FFT)

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

Have found this [other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841049/how-to-edit-raw-pcm-audio-data-without-an-audio-library) that talks about editing raw PCM audio data, but the libraries pointed to audioop and wave are probably not going to be directly usable in my case.

I intend to send/receive a byte-stream of PCM (LPCM, not ADPCM) encoded data, and might have to perform some basic DSP operations including FFT and amplification (gain-control). In my reading so far, I think I can use the FFT feature in scipy, but it is not yet clear to me, as to how I can deal with byte-stream (& not file) of PCM-encoded audio.

Of course, I do need the ability to read PCM data from a wave-file, to be streamed back, but for that, I think "[wave](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html)" library will do the job.

Have tried to go through the mega-list of libraries under [Python-in-Music](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) part of the Wiki, but it is overwhelming. Pointer to library that can do the job required, is 'Pythonic' in it's approach, well documented and that is also currently maintained, would be highly helpful.