# How can I extract the data points (corresponding y value for x values) from a waveplot

Tags: python, arrays, audio, librosa

I'm hoping this is an appropriate question for here.

I have used Python Librosa to plot a wave form for a sound file. I'm finding it difficult to extract the data points. e.g. what is the value of y, at x (Time) = 0.15 on this output below. I can't see this on the documentation for Librosa, so I' wondering if this can be done.

Here is the code I have based on Librosa documentation so far:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, sr = librosa.load('audio.wav')
bpm, beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)
plt.figure()
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr)
plt.show()
print (f'bpm: {bpm:.2f} beats per minute')
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTmMY.png)

Is it possible to get the x and y axis into an array for example, or at least print a single data point please?

Thank you

Comment: use this to plot your audio data  https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.waveshow.html  notice  librosa.display.waveplot has been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

librosa.display.waveplot compute and plots the *amplitude envelope* of the audio signal.
You can see how this is done by looking at the [source code of the function](https://librosa.org/doc/main/_modules/librosa/display.html#waveplot) (accessible via "view source" on the documentation page for the function).

Here is the relevant part of the code for computing the envelope.

```py
def __envelope(x, hop):
    """Compute the max-envelope of non-overlapping frames of x at length hop

    x is assumed to be multi-channel, of shape (n_channels, n_samples).
    """
    import numpy as np

    x_frame = np.abs(librosa.util.frame(x, frame_length=hop, hop_length=hop))
    return x_frame.max(axis=1)

# Reduce by envelope calculation
env = __envelope(y, hop_length)
```

Where `hop_length` is the number of audio samples per point of the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if any of the tools listed in the post [How to edit raw PCM audio data without an audio library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841049/how-to-edit-raw-pcm-audio-data-without-an-audio-library) might be helpful in getting the raw PCM you are seeking. Ideally, librosa library itself should allow a hook to view the PCM data array itself, but I've found that audio tools sometimes don't actually allow this (for example `Clip` in Java). If you can't locate a librosa hook, maybe obtaining the PCM array from one of these tools prior to or in parallel to shipping data to librosa would be helpful.